# Dog toilet training

Tags: dogs

My dog wee's in his bed if I put a blanket or pillow in there he also wee's and poos over my kitchen when I'm at work. He is a two year old bulldog. He has been castrated and the vets have checked him out for any infection or incontinence and is all clear. Some say a companion because he might be stressed out but I'd like any suggestions before I do go ahead with another dog for him

Comment: So we know about your dog. But what have you tried so far? A dog is never too old to learn, it might just be a tiny bit stubborn, lazy or something else. In other words: Have you tried classic potty training as described in many questions and answers here? Just ignore the fact your dog is no longer a puppy.

Comment: How long has it been since the last time he went out, when he messes in the kitchen while you are at work?  The first sentence "My dog wee's in his bed if I put a blanket or pillow in there" implies this only happens when you put a blanket or pillow in his bed, if that is the case don't put stuff in his bed, if it is not the case, please clarify the problem.

Comment: He sleeps in a crate at night and doesn't mess there.  He can only be left for 30 minutes and he's done something even though he has been outside or for a walk.  It seems to be happening every day now but there has been the rare occasion when the kitchen is clean when I get back.  I can't put any bedding in his crate at all because like I say he just wee's on it.  I've asked the vets what I need to do but to be honest they're not much help.  To clarify I leave the crate open in the day and closed at night.

Answer (score 2):

Crate training is my go to for house soiling. It must be big enough for the dog to stand up, lie down and turn around. If the crate is too large he will just soil in one spot and sleep in the other.

When he does his business outside be sure to reward him with treats (clicker training is always a good idea).

You can also hire someone to come by your place at lunch time to let him out.

Getting another dog to try and fix a problem is never a good idea, you may end up with two dogs soiling or two dogs anxious for your return. If a dog is missing his owner having a companion won't make him miss you less.

If he's anxious when home alone you can try doggy daycare or try some anti-anxiety medications (under a veterinarians guidance).

Comment: He sleeps in a crate at night and doesn't mess there. He can only be left for 30 minutes and he's done something even though he has been outside or for a walk. It seems to be happening every day now but there has been the rare occasion when the kitchen is clean when I get back. I can't put any bedding in his crate at all because like I say he just wee's on it. I've asked the vets what I need to do but to be honest they're not much help. To clarify I leave the crate open in the day and closed at night. – Nette71 Jul 25 at 7:37   delete